# Meditation for Work Anxiety

Tags: anxiety

I started a new job, and when I get anxious my cognition turns to pure incoherence. I second-guess everything, doubt, double-check unnecessarily, make more errors, etc.

**What is the best type of meditation to deal with such anxiety-related problems?**

Answer (score 2):

If the anxiety is light yet bothersome, gentle restrain anxiety by relinquishing attachment to outcome:

> This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self. [MN62](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato)

If the anxiety is heavier and a bit overwhelming, a firm restraint can be achieved by slowing the breath--rapid breathing promotes anxiety. Regular practice of mindfulness of breathing helps.

> When mindfulness of breathing is developed and cultivated it’s very fruitful and beneficial. [MN62](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato)

Generally, the more you practice the Noble Eight-Fold Path, the more equanimity emerges with the fading away of attachments to identity view. However, that practice and its fruition are gradual. For the longer term, precepts can be enormously helpful.

> A mendicant might wish: ‘May I prevail over fear and dread, and may fear and dread not prevail over me. May I live having mastered fear and dread whenever they arise.’ So let them fulfill their precepts … [AN10.71](https://suttacentral.net/an10.71/en/sujato)

Also consult with your doctor for additional recommendations. Some anxiety disorders can be quite crippling and medical assistance can be of great benefit.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main types of meditation:

- [Samatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samatha)
- [Vipassanā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81)

Samantha increases concentration. If you have concentration problems which lead to mistakes then this will help.

Vipassana meditation can help with stress and anxiety at work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the way I try to deal with it is

- Ethics e.g. being careful about what I say, not promising what I cannot deliver
- Having an altruistic attitude (*metta*), trying to cooperate and to provide what other people want

Also I kind of know that every job is temporary. The longest I worked anywhere was 12 years, and I have had contracts to do just a few weeks' work.

So I think you have to do a bit of what Oyamist said, i.e. "relinquishing attachment to outcome" -- sometimes there's work for me somwhere, and sometimes there isn't -- and whether and when that's so (i.e. whether people have a job for me) is somewhat outside my control.

So instead of concentrating on outcome ("what will happen?"), you concentrate on process ("how am I doing, am I communicating well?") -- then perhaps you develop a reputation, and so be able to find more work even after this job ends for whatever reason (but of course concentrate on one job at a time).

On the subject of meditation (which you asked about) I find walking ("walking meditation?") helpful. If "cognition turns to pure incoherence" then maybe walk around the block and breathe a bit. I do that, stand up, breathe, swing my arms a bit, use both feet, see a streetscape -- and without thinking about it too hard, and idea might come up like, "maybe I'll trying doing X next" -- and that seems like an idea that might work so I go back and try it.